# Removing space in Insert

Tags: sql, vb.net

How to remove the space in front of the ***FileID*** in below query. ***FileID*** is being inserted in database with a space.

```
  CommandText = "Insert into FileMaster(Subject,FileID) 
                 Values('" & obj.Subject & "',' " & obj.FileID & "')
```

Thanks

Comment: http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/005/545/OpoQQ.jpg

Comment: Just remove space from inserting value `'" & obj.FileID & "'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the extra space:

```
CommandText = "Insert into FileMaster(Subject,FileID) Values('" & obj.Subject & "','" & obj.FileID & "')
```

And be aware that you are open to SQL Injection attacks with ad-hoc queries like this.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @ta.speot.is, thanks.  I forgot my usual sql injection warning.